# Parse array of arrays in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I am trying to parse an array of arrays, but I get error

```
Reference found where even-sized list expected
```

Here is the program:

```
use Modern::Perl;

my @info=(
      ['k1','v1',1,2],
      ['k2','v2',2,3]
    );

my %names=getNames(\@info);

sub getNames {
    my ($info) = @_;
    my %names;
    foreach my $item (@$info) {
       $names{@$item[0]}=@$item[1];
    }
    return \%names;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ivan pointed out, your `return` value does not match what you're assigning it to:

```
my %names = getNames(\@info);

sub getNames {
    ...
    return \%names;
}
```

`%names` excepts an even number of elements because it's a hash, but you're assigning it a reference to a hash, which is a single element.  Hence the error.

This line of your subroutine is also a little suspect: `$names{@$item[0]}=@$item[1];`.  Perhaps you meant to use `$names{$item->[0]}=$item->[1];`?

If you're trying to translate the array of arrays into a hash with keys pointing at the remaining values, you can use the following:

```
my @info=(
      ['k1','v1',1,2],
      ['k2','v2',2,3],
    );

my %names = map {$_->[0] => [@{$_}[1..$#$_]]} @info;

use Data::Dump;
dd \%names;
```

Outputs:

```
{ k1 => ["v1", 1, 2], k2 => ["v2", 2, 3] }
```

If however, you're just wanting the first "value", then the following would be sufficient:

```
my %names = map {$_->[0] => $_->[1]} @info;
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're trying to assign hash reference to hash `my %names=getNames(\@info);`. Change it to work with reference:

```
my $names = getNames(\@info);
```

Or return hash:

```
return %names;
```